# Messing around with Ember animate outlets

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am messing around with phonegap and ember outlet animations and came across the problem that if you have a 5 tab view that sometimes the animation needs to be swipe left and other times swipe right. So I started writing out a solution that I thought *should* work.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  currentView: 1, // views are 1-5
  actions: {
    goToFeed: function() {
      if(this.get('currentView') == 1) {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        this.transitionToAnimated('index', {main: 'slideRight'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      }
      this.set('currentView', 1);
    },
    goToTopTier: function() {
      if(this.get('currentView') == 2) {
        // do nothing
      } else if(this.get('currentView') < 2) {
        this.transitionToAnimated('toptier', {main: 'slideRight'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      } else {
        this.transitionToAnimated('toptier', {main: 'slideLeft'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      }
      this.set('currentView', 2);
    },
    goToSchools: function() {
      if(this.get('currentView') == 3) {
        // do nothing
      } else if(this.get('currentView') < 3) {
        this.transitionToAnimated('schools', {main: 'slideRight'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      } else {
        this.transitionToAnimated('schools', {main: 'slideLeft'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      }
      this.set('currentView', 3);
    },
    goToFriends: function() {
      if(this.get('currentView') == 4) {
        // do nothing
      } else if(this.get('currentView') < 4) {
        this.transitionToAnimated('friends', {main: 'slideRight'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      } else {
        this.transitionToAnimated('friends', {main: 'slideLeft'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      }
      this.set('currentView', 4);
    },
    goToProfile: function() {
      if(this.get('currentView') == 4) {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        this.transitionToAnimated('index', {main: 'slideLeft'}, function() { return App.CARDS; });
      }
      this.set('currentView', 4);
    }
  }
});
```

Reading through it, it makes sense to me but I get an error saying undefined is not a function. Looking at billysbilling's documentation I followed his instructions of `transitionToAnimated(name, animations, model)`.

If i could just do a simple {{#if view < somevalue}} then this would be perfect but we can't do that in ember.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

So I figured why the function was recognized. It was because `this.transitionToAnimated` only works within `Ember.Route` when i was within an `Ember.ArrayController`. So I fixed that but I still get an error. I'll keep working at it but any help would be appreciated.